# Laravel Middleware Authorization by User Role

Tags: php, laravel

I have added a column to my `users` table called `role`. Here is my migration:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->enum('role', ['admin', 'manager', 'employee'])->default('employee');
});
```

In my `api.php` is there a way to only allow access to the routes for users of a certain role?

So for the middleware, these routes are only available to users with the role of `admin`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->prefix('/admin')->group(function (): void {
    Route::post('/manager', [AdminController::class, 'addManager']);
    Route::delete('/manager/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'deleteManager']);
    Route::post('/department', [AdminController::class, 'addDepartment']);
});
```

In this possible?

Comment: There is route middleware - are you asking how to add this to your routes or how to write the middleware itself?

Comment: Well, I researched more and found out about Gates and Policies which seems to be what I want to implement

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/create-middleware-to-auth-admin-users?page=0